# How to check if value is datestring or double in Swifty json?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am parsing json using Swifty json. Now i have a key as `"create_date"` which can have a timestamp & as well as a date string like "2017-08-17 20:00:00".Now i am not sure when it will be a string date or it is a timestamp.I am using below code to parse this

```
if  let timeInterval = dic?["created_at"].doubleValue  {
    print("timeinterval is \(timeInterval)")
    date1 = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: (timeInterval / 1000))
    date = self.getStrDateFromDate(dob: date1!) as String
}
```

if use `dict["create_date"].doubleValue` so if it a string date then it r return me 2017  & in case of timestamp it return some timestamp as 15383673563465 .

Now how do i identify if is a date or a timestamp ?

Comment: Just add a type cast at the end of the `if let`.

Comment: if your dict is JSON then you can `if let timeInterval = dic?["created_at"].string{}`

Comment: in case of time stamp it will also a string i think . i have added condition if it contains "-"

Comment: With that example timestamp string it's likely you'd have to divide by 10000 rather than 1000. Just a guess, since dividing by 10000 gives a date-time of Oct 1, 2018, 00:15 and dividing by 1000 makes it Jun 27, 2457, 14:39.

Answer (score 1):

Use optional binding and cast down the value to `Double` with the `double` property of SwiftyJSON. If the downcast succeeds create the string from the `Date` otherwise use the date string directly.

```
let dateString : String
if let timeInterval = dic?["created_at"].double  {
    print("timeinterval is \(timeInterval)")
    date1 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval / 1000)
    dateString = self.getStrDateFromDate(dob: date1!) as String
} else {
    dateString = dic?["created_at"].stringValue
}
```

Side note:

Why do you (bridge) cast a result to string (from `getStrDateFromDate`) which is supposed to be a string?

Answer (score 0):

I would try a `DateFormatter` with the format of your possible date string, then try to convert it to a double. Or vise-versa. The order really doesn't matter too much, although it may be slightly less expensive to check for the double first.

```
import Foundation

func convertDate(dateString:String) -> Date? {
  // try `Double`
  if let timestamp = Double(dateString) {
    return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp)
  }

  // try `DateFormatter`
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
  if let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) {
    return date
  }

  // give up
  return nil
}

let dateString1 = String(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
let dateString2 = "2017-08-17 20:00:00"
let dateString3 = "something"

print(convertDate(dateString: dateString1) ?? "unknown")
print(convertDate(dateString: dateString2) ?? "unknown")
print(convertDate(dateString: dateString3) ?? "unknown")

// 2017-08-17 15:15:27 +0000
// 2017-08-18 00:00:00 +0000
// unknown
```

Note that the default `description` for a `Date` uses GMT. In my case it's off by 4 hours, which is why the displayed time is 4 hours different from I entered.